# syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rvm, whenever

I am using whenever(whenever (0.8.2)) in my rails project('rails', '3.2.11'). Everything that is given in the readme of the whenever is present in my schedule.rb but when i try to use cron job during execution it don't complete but gives me some error in my error.log file:-

**Error:-**

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `('
`APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)'
```

If any one is having any idea about this please let me know i tried a lot but still got nothing

cron job is working for my other project on the same system but can't figure out what is the issue with this one.

My schedule.rb:-

```
set :output, {:error => 'error.log', :standard => 'cron.log'}

every :day, :at => '1:00 am' do
   runner "Site.daily_stats"
end

every 2.minutes do
  runner "Notifier.testing_whenever.deliver"
end
```

Comment: show the code part, where `APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)` has been written

Comment: Please paste in the code, not just the error

Comment: Keep in mind that a `cron` job runs in its own shell and may not have the same environment variable setup as when you are executing from your normal shell. So check that.

Comment: Error in the line `APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)'`.. show the code , where  this line exist

Comment: This file is present in script directory under name railsAPP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'

Comment: @ArupRakshit any idea about this

Comment: I am not finding any syntax error here.

Comment: can you give the full error stack.. from there I can locate it

Comment: @ArupRakshit The error i mentioned above is the only error that keeps on comming nothing else.

Comment: what is the command you run (or the configuration that makes it run) show the file that gets executed, did you tried prefixing the command/file with `ruby -dw`?

Comment: @mpapis this is present in my script directory/ rails. This command will run automatically when load rails

Comment: you mean you run `rails`? then show us output from: `ruby -dwS rails`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey finally I got the solution the problem was in rails file in script director.
Make sure this file starts with this line :- #!/usr/bin/env ruby
and in my file in the starting there was just a blank space and then this line was present.

Remove that space and now everything is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you modify Rails files (i.e. by adding Copyright comments) so that the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

is no more the first line. Of course, it should be the very first line on all of your scripts, especially 'bin/rails'